# going thru Databases and have lots of confusion wanted answers

Tags: select, view, rdbms, statements

i am studying Databases and have a few questions.

Q1.when i fire a select query where is the result stored?? 
Q2. views take less memory as only the query is stored as an object and not the data. but when a use a view i get a subset of the data . doesn't that subset occupy space. should we not execute a select query directly then ?

Answer (score 0):

A1. When you execute a SELECT query the results are returned to your client application and often displayed on your screen but are not stored anywhere unless you explicitly choose to store them. You can think of the result of a SELECT query as a 'picture' of the data at a point in time, not a copy of the data.

A2. As mentioned above, the data returned by a SELECT does not occupy any space so a view is a convenient way of saving a query.